# How to force mapping in copy activity of Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from a cosmosdb container to an Azure SQL database table using Azure Data Factory.
Some of my columns in cosmosdb are not mandatory and might not be defined. The issue is that for every of these columns, I get the following error when running the copy activity :

```
Data type of column 'MyProperty' can't be inferred from 1st row of data, please specify its data type in mappings of copy activity or structure of DataSet.
```

However I checked in the mapping tab and the types of these properties are correctly infered to string, and they are well nullable in my SQL stored procedure table type.

I also have the same problem for optional decimal properties where the errors says that the value can't be parsed to Int64, though the infered type in the mapping tab is set to number and not integer...

Here is the mapping I currently have :
[image]

And the stored procedure with the table type

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyTableType] AS TABLE
(
    [Id] varchar(256) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [SupplierId] varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    [SupplierClientId] varchar(256) NULL,
    [BuyerId] varchar(256) null
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpsertItems]
    @itemsTable MyTableType readonly
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE MyTable AS target
    USING @itemsTable AS source
    ON (target.Id = source.Id)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET 
            SupplierId = source.SupplierId,
            SupplierClientId = source.[SupplierClientId],
            BuyerId = source.[BuyerId]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (Id, SupplierId, SupplierClientId, BuyerId)
      VALUES (
        source.Id, 
        source.SupplierId, 
        source.[SupplierClientId], 
        source.[BuyerId]);
END
```

I can't find a way to force the datatype of this property either in the dataset directly of in the mapping tab of the copy activity. How can I fix the issue ?

Comment: Were you able to workaround this ?

Comment: What I ended up doing is to create a buffer table in SQL and make the copy from cosmosdb to this table using the auto create table option in the sink dataset. This way adf seems to be ok with nullable/undefined properties. Then I use another copy activity with the stored procedure to merge the buffer table with the target table. Finally I flush the buffer table. Kind of a heavy solution in my opinion but at least it works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the data types if you are creating a new table while copy. But if you are adding or copying to an already existing table, the data type is inferred automatically.

[image]

While, auto creating table in copying

[image]

If this does not help, please share sample source data and some snips

Comment: You can use, `Pre-copy script` to alter table column data types [refer Pre and Post SQL scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database?tabs=data-factory#:~:text=Pre%20and%20Post%20SQL%20scripts)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes it works when using auto create table, it is not what I need though because I am calling a stored procedure to insert or update the data if it already exists. Also I am only using copy data activity not data flow, I thought I did not need it for that since the mapping seemed to be quite straightforward.

Comment: Were you able to workaround this? did you try `Pre-copy scripts` ? You can map the columns dynamically as explained [here](https://sqlitybi.com/dynamically-set-copy-activity-mappings-in-azure-data-factory-v2/) but if the issue is with Matching Data types while copying to an existing table, am afraid there is no direct way in adf without using dataflows.

Comment: you can log a request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/search/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c?q=%22data+type%22) to bring to notice